# Defining a function of a distribution

Tags: functions, distributions, pure-function, markov-chains

I have a discrete- time and space markov process that I want to evolve given an initial distribution.

To that, I defined

```
TimeP[initial_, state_, 0] := initial[state];
TimeP[initial_, state_, t_] := TimeP[initial, state, t] = TimeP[initial, state, t - 1] + ...
```

where the initial distribution would be something like this:

```
initial[state_] := 0
initial[firstState] := 1
```

and `...` are probabilities to jump from a state to another state.

Now, with the above definition of `TimeP`, I can correctly evolve the probabilities. However, when I define another initial distribution, say

```
Clear[initial]
initial[state_] := 0
initial[firstState1] := 1
```

The function `TimeP` gets confused because it only stores the name `initial`, and not its definition (i.e. even if `initial` has now a different definition, `TimeP` returns the computed value from `initial`'s definition of `firstState`, and not `firstState1`.

So, my question is: is a way of telling `TimeP` that its argument's name doesn't matter, only the actual definition that matters? Or, do you know a better way of implementing this?

This is what I would expect: the function `initial` is defining a distribution, and the distribution's definition is on its probabilities. When I change `initial`'s definition to another values, `TimeP` would give another result.

(I'm not using Mathematica's `DiscreteMarkovProcess` because the transition matrix is almost diagonal with most entries equal to 0, and the number of states is large).

Comment: It would seem strange to me to rename your initial state whenever you want to specify a new initial distribution (`firstState` vs `firstState1`). Can you not simply assign a different value to `initial[firstState]`? Also, do you have a value set for `firstState`?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a direct answer to your question, but it can helps you.

I think it is more efficient to work with sparse arrays and store the resulting distribution in an array, not in `DownValues`.

```
n = 100;

m = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 0.5, Band[{1, 2}] -> 0.25, 
   Band[{2, 1}] -> 0.25}, {n, n}];

init = 50;

p0 = MapAt[1. &, #, init] &@ConstantArray[0., n];

p = NestList[m.# &, p0, 100];

ListPlot3D[p, PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}]
```

[image]

Approach with the memoization:

```
distr[init_, t_] := distr[init, t] = m.distr[init, t - 1];
distr[init_, 0] := m.MapAt[1. &, #, init] &@ConstantArray[0., n];

ListLinePlot[{distr[50, 100], distr[75, 100], distr[50, 200]}]
```

[image]